# LiveData Observer is not working in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        viewModel.isDialogOpen.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { isDialogOpen ->
            if (!isDialogOpen) {
                this@Fragment.closeAllBaseDialogFragments()
            }
        }
```

```
fun saveConfiguration() {
        if (saveJob == null) {
            saveJob = viewModelScope.launch {
                withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    setUpProfile()
                    L.saveState(
                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                        context.sendBroadcast(Intent (FloorPlanFragment.ACTION_BLE_PAIRING_COMPLETED));
                        ProgressDialogUtils.hideProgressDialog()
                        _isDialogOpen.value = false
                    }
                }

                // This check is needed because the dialog sometimes fails to close inside the coroutine.
                // We don't know why this happens.
                if (ProgressDialogUtils.isDialogShowing()) {
                    ProgressDialogUtils.hideProgressDialog()
                    _isDialogOpen.value = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have set btn when I clikced the set btn it set the Live data variable (isDialogOpen)  to  false ,but sometimes observe is not observing it .It is not coming inside the if condition